# How to update a variable value from a loop A to another loop B - in bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, infinite-loop, updating

I am increasing the value of a variable in a first loop and using it in a second loop.

**My problem:** the variable doesn't change in the second loop. (It's an example, I know that I can move the code that changes the value from the loop into the function but I have a program with multiple functions and multiple loops).

**My question:** how to update the value of a variable (increasing inside a first while loop) in a second while loop?

Here is an **illustration** (First loop is increasing the counter_value but the second loop stick to "1") :

```
#!/bin/bash

counter_value="1"

function Print_counter_value () {
    echo $counter_value ; }

#_____FIRST LOOP_____
while : ; do # infinite loop
      #echo first loop works
      counter_value=$[$counter_value+1]
      echo $counter_value 1st_loop & sleep 2
done &

#_____SECOND LOOP_____
while : ; do # infinite loop
      #echo second loop works
      Print_counter_value & sleep 1
done &
```

Thank you!

Comment: Move the code that changes the value from the loop into the function?

Comment: @choroba Thanks for your answer but it's an example. Actually I have multiple loops calling the same variable so it's better for me to to update the variable in each loops than move the code 50 times.

Comment: Bash processes don't and can't share variables. You'd have to write the value to a file/pipe/fifo or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that increments the variable:

```
((counter_value++))
```

There's no need to put the second loop into the background.  Saving the variable to a file is a little clumbsy, but it works.

```
#!/bin/bash

counter_value=1
file="/tmp/temp$$"
echo "counter_value=$counter_value" > "$file"

function Print_counter_value () {
    echo $counter_value ; }

#_____FIRST LOOP_____
while : ; do # infinite loop
    . "$file"
    ((counter_value++))
    echo "counter_value=$counter_value" > "$file"
    sleep 2
done &

#_____SECOND LOOP_____
while : ; do # infinite loop
    . "$file"
    Print_counter_value & sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Thanks you for you answer. Could you please explain a bit more? I have replace the line containg counter_value=$[$counter_value+1] by ((counter_value++) but it doesn't work.

Comment: The second loops still stick to 1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with variables.

By using the `&` sign at the end of each loop, you're **forking** the process, i.e. you're creating a new process which will run the loop code. Each of these two new processes will have its own address spaces ==> `counter_value` is a different one from the one in the parent process. Writing to it will change its value neither in the parent process nor in the sibling process. Only the local one will be updated.

> "I know that I can move the code that changes the value from the loop into the function"

Moving this code won't change anything. Both child-processes will call this function but each will read/write its own `counter_value` and changes of the first loop won't be reflected in what the second loop reads.

In order to see/"believe" that it's a different process, you can print inside the loops the variables `$$` (PID) and `$BASHPID` (PID of the child-process or the sub-shell). You'll notice that they're different from each other.

If you want these processes to update each other's data you'll have to use, as mentioned in the comments, other methods. And keep in mind that you might run into concurrency issues.